.Net - how to parse histogram metrics using TraceEvent?
I am collecting metrics from one .net app in another using DiagnosticsClient:
            var providers = new List<EventPipeProvider>()
            {
                new EventPipeProvider("System.Diagnostics.Metrics", EventLevel.Verbose, keywords: -1, arguments: new Dictionary<string, string>
                {
                    ["Metrics"] = "SomeApi",
                    ["Metrics"] = "MyApp",
                }),
            };

            client = new DiagnosticsClient(pid);
            session = client.StartEventPipeSession(providers, requestRundown: false);

            source = new EventPipeEventSource(session.EventStream);

            source.Dynamic.All += (TraceEvent obj) =>
            {
                if (obj.PayloadNames.Length < 7) return;

                var n = obj.PayloadValue(3) as string; 
                var v = obj.PayloadValue(6) as string; 

                //[0]: "sessionId"
                //[1]: "meterName"
                //[2]: "meterVersion"
                //[3]: "instrumentName"
                //[4]: "unit"
                //[5]: "tags"
                //[6]: "lastValue"
            };

So I figured that payload index 6 is value for a "plane" metric like a counter. But if it is a histogram or observable gauge then there is no value.
I want to print values same as dotnet-counters does:

EDIT: my code is based on 2 sources:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/diagnostics/diagnostics-client-library
https://www.meziantou.net/getting-telemetry-data-from-inside-or-outside-a-dotnet-application.htm#diagnostic-event-pip

Instead of creating your own custom library it's better to use the industry standard OpenTelemetry which is supported out of the box (and actually working even though you don't realize it). As for metrics, they're collected through the Metrics namespace and can be forwarded to Prometheus or any OpenTelemetry-compatible service simply through configuration. Your code is already collecting such metrics

I suggest checking the simple .NET Aspire example to see that you don't have to add any custom code to the Blazor and Web API projects to generate traces and metrics. Traces, metrics and logs are forwarded to the Dashboard where they're correlated and displayed

You seem to be building a Web API. In that case check the built-in ASP.NET Core metrics.

That's a great way to drive off people that want to help. Especially when you seem to be mixing the new Metrics API with the older EventCounters. Are you sure you can read Metrics with the older API at all? If you want to produce output like dotnet-counters, you can check the source code

The Metrics comparison docssay that EventCounters are able to report rates of change and averages, but do not support histograms and percentiles.

I think the source you need is here : dotnet-counters uses different code to handle Metrics and older diagnostic events. You'll have to do the same

OK. Short version. You're using the wrong API. Use the correct one.

I had to "hack" it, for histograms the values are in "quantiles" :
if (obj.PayloadNames.Length == 9)
    v = obj.PayloadByName("quantiles") as string;

